# Can I create an undo record in an Excel 2007 add-in?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-2007, undo

Currently, when my add-in makes changes to a worksheet it also destroys the document history and the changes can't be undone. Is there any way to make the changes undoable?

Word 2010 exposes the [Application.UndoRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff838675.aspx) property etc. I think I need something similar to that, but for Excel 2007. I'm working in C# using VSTO, and the change in this case is just a single write to the Value2 property of a Range, i.e.:

```
OutRange.Value2 = Output;
```